# Opening a new window on a tableview row click in titanium

Tags: titanium, tableview

I am trying to open a new window by click a row in tableview in titanium.

this is my code,

```
function listpage(){

   var tabgroup=Ti.UI.createTabGroup();

   var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
      title:'Listpage',
      backgroundColor:'#fff'    
   });

   var dataArray = [{
            title:'Sunday',
            hasChild:true,
            test:'detail'}];

   for(var i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++){
        dataArray[i].color = '#000';
        dataArray[i].font  = {fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:20};
   }     

   var tableview=Ti.UI.createTableView({
       data:dataArray   
   });

    tableview.addEventListener('click',function(e){
       if(e.rowData){
           Ti.API.info(e.rowData.title);    

           var winEvent = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
               backgroundColor:'#fff',  
               url:e.rowData.test
           });
          winEvent.open({animation:true});

       }    
   });

   win.add(tableview);

   win.open();

}
```

detail.js code :

```
var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title:'Detail',
    color:'#000',
    backgroundColor:'white'
});

var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text:'Hai',
    color:'#000'
});
self.add(label);
```

What to do to open detail.js window by clicking tableview row.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Surendra, this is something similar to your problem. It opens a window while you clicks on each row.

Code is

```
var wndHome = Ti.UI.createWindow({
     backgroundColor : 'white'
});

var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView({
     top : 0
});

var tabledata = [];
for(var i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        title : 'Title of window',
        url   : 'details.js'
    });
    tabledata.push(row);
}
tableView.data = tabledata;
wndHome.add(tableView);
wndHome.open();


tableView.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var wndNewWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor : '#999966',
        url             : e.rowData.url
    });

    wndNewWindow.open();
});
```

**details.js file**

```
var self = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text:'Hai',
    color:'#000'
});
self.add(label);
```

Here I've given the url to details.js. If you want to use different windows, then keep the file names in an array and while creating the tableViewRow, you can simply add the array element as the url(eg: `fileArray = ['file1.js', 'file2.js','file3.js'];`).

*Try this and change your code as per your requirement.*